# Add dynamic value to a hidden form field

Tags: php, hidden-field

I'm having a contact form field named, **addons** with **select options**

it's code is

```
<?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $options->addon_name; ?>"><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Every addon have it's unique price. It can be fetch through **$options->addon_price;** I added only addon name in contact form so i'm getting only it's name once user submits form. Likewise, I need to get that addon price too without creating new field and asking users to select price in dropdown.

Any ideas to do this ?

Comment: So, if the name is not unique, but the price is, you don't need the name as value - put the price as value? If you need both, you need two inputs. `<option value="unique_field">What user is seeing</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following trick:

```
<?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $options->addon_name.','.$options->addon_price; ?>">
        <h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5>
</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Add the price with the name in value of dropdown and then after submitting the page you can get the string with name and price and then you can split it with the `,` by using the explode function like it:

```
$pieces = explode(",", $str);
```

And you can use the price and name by `$name = $pieces[0]` and `$price = $pieces[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working like a charm. I have one final issue,.. if i print $pieces i'm getting Array
(
    [0] => Banner flash  7 to 8 images
    [1] => 1000
Scripting Banners
    [2] => 3500
5 Content Pages ( Max 500 words per page)
    [3] => 250} Grouping is not happening properly

Comment: @Vin_fugen may be your name field has `,` with the value for escape that you can use any other symbol to add the name and price instead of `,` and that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

```
<?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $options->addon_price; ?>"><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
<?php } ?>
```

and u can fetch the price form the drop down

Comment: sekhar muk... Thanks for your quick reply.. If i do so i'm getting email like Chosen Addon: 1300. I think u didnt understood my question. Admin need to get both addon name and addon price. But user should select only addon name from select option.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this you will be able to get the price and it will show addon_name to the user.

```
<?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $options->addon_price; ?>"><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. If i do so i'm getting email like Chosen Addon: 1300. I think u didnt understood my question. Admin need to get both addon name and addon price. But user should select only addon name from select option. Is it possible do it through dynamic hidden field.

Comment: you can pass two values as string having a delimiter to parse as array to get both the values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a unique ID to identify the addons. If it's a static array that doesn't change, you can even use the array keys for that purpose, but I would add an addon_id field to the objects.

The addons array would be something like this:

```
$addons = array(
    1 => $addon1,
    2 => $addon2,
    3 => $addon3,
    ... etc
);
```

Your select options can have the array keys as values:

```
<?php foreach ($addons as $key => $options) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Then when you're processing the selected addon, use the key to access the appropriate addon, like so:

```
$selected_addon = $addons[$_POST['addon']];
```

, obviously substituting the correct form element name, and sanitizing the input first, this is just to give you an idea.